# cache.html size in gwt and Slow-Loading

Tags: caching, gwt, load, startup

in my GWT project when I tested it by firebug I saw the ...cache.html file size is very big (about 700KB) and it cause for slow-loading the project for first time.
In my project it can be a problem.

how to prevent size for cache.html in GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [Code Splitting](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html) to only load what's needed as it's needed.
2. Use [Compile Reports](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html) to find out which of your dependencies is causing your code size to be so huge, and (re)move them from the initial download.